# const int*& vs typedef int* IntPtr

Tags: c++

Why is it that I have to change the `int *` to a `typedef int * IntPtr` for this to compile?

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    public:
        template <class X>
        void a(X *x, void (X::*fun)(const T&))
        {
        }
};

typedef int * IntPtr;

class B
{
    public:
        B() : a()
        {
            a.a(this, &B::foo); // this won't work
        }
        void foo(const int *&) // must replace `int *` here with `IntPtr`
        {
        }
        A<int *> a; // ...and here
};

class C
{
    public:
        C() : a()
        {
            a.a(this, &C::foo);
        }
        void foo(const IntPtr&)
        {
        }
        A<IntPtr> a;
};
```

I understand why typedefs are useful but not why they are required. the class `C` compiles fine `B` does not.

This is the error from MSVC++ 2008 compiler:

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'void A<T>::a(X *,void (__thiscall X::* )(const T &))' : could not deduce template argument for 'void (__thiscall X::* )(const T &)' from 'void (__thiscall B::* )(const int *&)'
```

Comment: Can you post the code as it was when it wouldn't compile?

Comment: I'll check that this code reproduces the issue (it should). I'm currently using the MSVC 2008 compiler.

Comment: @MvG yeah, that's not it, while it's obviously wrong... I just ran the above code in the MSVC 2008 compiler, I'd like to know why the `*` makes a difference, it's just a type, isn't it?

Comment: As john mentioned, it should be void foo(int * const &);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`const int*&` and `typedef int* IntPtr; const IntPtr&` are not the same. In the first case it's the int that's constant, in the second case it's the pointer. Only the second case is compatible with your template.

If you write

```
void foo(int * const &);
```

instead, it should compile and work just fine.

Comment: This is, of course, why you should always put the `const` after.  If you write `IntPtr const`, it's clear that this is not `int const*`, but `int *const`.