# const correctness and template arguments

Tags: c++

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778490/c-compiler-nuisance) if you want a bit of back story.

I want to pass things as immutable data.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    public:
        void send(const T& value);
};

A<int> a;
a.send(1);
```

So far, so good. I just sent a constant value but when I use a pointer things get tricky.

```
A<int *> a;
int b = 1;
a.send(&b);
```

What I eventually end up with is this:

```
void send(int *const & value)
```

I'm now passing a pointer that cannot be changed as a reference but the content that this pointer points to can be changed. This is correct but I'd like to express that you can't modify the content that this pointer points to.

My intent here is to make the thing immutable but is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you basically want a pointer specialisation, so how about this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Immutable {
  typedef T const& Type;
};

template <typename U>
struct Immutable<U*> {
  typedef U const* Type;
};

template<class T>
class A {
  public:
    void send(typename Immutable<T>::Type);
};
```

Comment: Alright, this looks promising. Do you know if there's anything like this in the STL?

Comment: @EricFinn I guess if you carry the semantic of a const reference you should prevent accidental assignment as well.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: No, I don't think so. This is not a very general problem, I suppose. What would come close would be: `remove_pointer` + `add_const` + `add_lvalue_reference`, but you would always end up with a `const&`, even if `T` was a pointer type.

Comment: I kinda feels as if I'm trying to solve a problem that doesn't really need a solution...

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: I agree. Even if I look at your backstory-question, I have no clue why this would be useful. Maybe you have other issues in your design?

Comment: It's not that far-fetched, I have messages that get sent, these messages are for all intent and purposes immutable. I'd like to capture this in my design. I have templates that take the message type as type parameters and this got messy when I started using pointers in one place. I don't have to care about that because it's not going to be involving pointers in the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could declare `a` as

```
A<const int *> a;
```

Comment: Okay, but this changes the semantic. Any const qualifier introduced by the class `A` is now redundant. And if there is a function which doesn't imply immutable it can no longer modify the value because it's  type has been made const by the user of this type.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: No, the const qualifier introduced by class `A` applies to the parameter (`const int *const&`).

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I see what you mean and it looks like a solution along the lines of the specialization proposed by bitmask could work.